# IBM Mobilefirst server installation fails to register an app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

I just installed MobileFirst server on Windows Server 2012.
I have MySQL as the database and Apache Tomcat 7 as the application server.
I can access the MobilFirst console, but whenever I try to register an application I get an error saying:
Connection Error. Contact the server administrator(HTTP code:405)

```
angular-layer.min.js:98 POST http://192.168.211.96:8080/mfpconsole/services/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/applications?async=true 405 (Method Not Allowed)
angular-layer.min.js:112 Failed request: /mfpconsole/services/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/applications
```

Comment: How do you access the server? Through WLResourceRequest? obtainAccessToken()  ? How?

Comment: I access the server with `WLResourceRequest`, but this is irrelevant, because I think I have a problem with the server configuration, which would not let me register the app, let alone have my app connect to the server.

Comment: It is important. Method not allowed means you are accessing a method that is set for some other HTTP method. Can you verify your adapter code ? Specifically the HTTP method set for the adapter method you are accessing